# How to iterate twice in an ansible task

Tags: ansible

In my ansible script, I want to iterate first with a list of variables, and on each variable, script must loop over another variable. For example :

```
- name: List files to delete
  find:
    path: "{{ myPath }}/data"
    excludes: '*int.yml*,*int-prod.yml*'
  register: files_to_delete
  with_items:
    - "{{ versions }}"
  when: item.name == 'registryInternet'

- name: Delete of all file in "files_to_delete"
  file:
    path: "{{ files_to_delete.path }}"
    state: absent
  with_items:
    - "{{ versions }}"
  loop_control:
    loop_var: files_to_delete
  when: item.name == 'registryInternet'
```

But it doesn't work, i think that with_item and loop command are similar and cannot be used together but I don't find how to iretate on it.

For each item in version, if when clause is OK, I have to delete all file in result of find command...

Thx for your help

Comment: Your `find` task does not make any use of the loop variable. What exactly are you trying to do? As is each iteration of `find` will return the same set of files.

Comment: Previous answer (deleted) with with_nested is ok for me. Thx for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```yaml
- name: find files to delete
  find:
    path: "{{ item }}"
  register: files_to_delete
  loop: "{{ to_delete }}"

- name: show found files
  debug:
    msg: "{{ item | map(attribute='path') }}"
  loop: "{{ files_to_delete.results | map(attribute='files') | list }}"
```

This returns all the found files. As you can imagine, configure the tasks to match your use-case...